# How to split a string by " | " in split method of String class in Java

Tags: java

I would like to split a String by " | " in Java. I found split method of String class and it expects a regex expression for split delimeter but I don't know how to form a regex expression for " | ".

For example, a string is "AA | BB | CC" and I would like to get only AA, BB and CC as a string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String string = "AA|BB|CC";
String[] arr = string.split("\\|");
for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The above code prints:

```
AA
BB
CC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression for that, but the `|` char is a special char so you must scape it.

`"AA | BB | CC".split("\\s*\\|\\s*");`

Answer (score 1):

It is `string.split("\\|")` (pipe must be escaped).

Answer (score 1):

| is a special character in a regexp so you have to escape it.

Try: 
`string.split("\\|")`

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression passed to the `split` method should be: `\\|`.

```
String text = "AA | BB | CC";
text.split("\\|")); // [AA ,  BB ,  CC]
```

If you want to get rid of the spaces then:

```
text.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")); // [AA, BB, CC]
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is an keyword in RegEX.

`String.split()` takes RegEx as argument. You have to escape it. You can do this.

```
string.split(" \\| ");
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.split("\\|")` does the work.

- split() splits the string according to regex
- `\` is needed to escape the regex' meaning of the pipe as "or"
- second back slash is need to escape the first back slash for java compiler.