# How to split a string in Java programming language?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm working on my programming assignment, and trying to understand an issue occuring with **String#split()** method in Java. I've tried for 3 hours and then asking- **How to split a string in Java. Here is the code snippet of it-**

**The Program**

```
class FileProcessor
{
    public static void fileNameProcessor(String fileName)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n---- PROCESSING FILE NAMES -----\n\n");
    
        fileName = "SampleName.java";                   // Let's assume the method receives this string
        String fileNameParts[] = fileName.split(".");

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNameParts.length; i++)
            System.out.println("File Information : " + fileNameParts[i]);

        System.out.println("\n\n------ END OF PROCESSING -------\n\n");
    }
}
```

**Here is the desired output:**

```
---- PROCESSING FILE NAMES -----


File Information : SampleName
File Information : java


------ END OF PROCESSING -------
```

**Output that I'm getting:**

```
---- PROCESSING FILE NAMES -----




------ END OF PROCESSING -------
```

I'm wondering, although the string has a dot `.` in it, yet the `split()` method is not performing its functionality. Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). String.split() uses regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

---

**Hope, This might help you the Best** - [Top 5 uses of String split() method in Java](https://shubhamklogic.com/how-to-use-split-in-java-a-modern-guide/)

---

The **String#split()** method takes Regular Expression as input.

**A regular expression is not a regular string**. In Regular expression- the dot (.) has a special meaning because it is a metacharacter. It tells the Java to select any character not just the literal dot .

In order to fix your code, you must Escape the dot by using two backslashes before the period or dot . Like this - `"\\."`

**The Solution**

```
class FileProcessor
{
    public static void fileNameProcessor(String fileName)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n---- PROCESSING FILE NAMES -----\n\n");
    
        fileName = "SampleName.java";                     // Assume that the File Name
        String fileNameParts[] = fileName.split("\\.");   // Escaping the dot (.) by double backslash \\.

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNameParts.length; i++)
            System.out.println("File Information : " + fileNameParts[i]);

        System.out.println("\n\n------ END OF PROCESSING -------\n\n");
    }
}
```

**Find Detailed Information Here-**

- [Top 5 uses of split() method of Java](https://shubhamklogic.com/how-to-use-split-in-java-a-modern-guide/)
- [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)

**Related Questions-**

- [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)
- [Other Similar Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934027/how-to-split-a-string-by-in-split-method-of-string-class-in-java)

**List of Metacharacter in Regex:**
There are some special characters in Regular expression with some special meanings: the asterisk or star `*`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.` , the plus sign `+`, and [others](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#meta-characters)

**That's all about How to split a string in Java using split() method** and Don't forget to use double the double backslash `\\` whenever splitting with a metacharacter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape the . character.

```
String fileNameParts[] = fileName.split("\\.");
```